# Can this expression be written without brackets or back-ticks?

Tags: haskell, function-composition

```
mul (add 2 3) 5
```

Can the dot (`.`) and dollar (`$`) operators alone replace the brackets?
The `mul` and `add` functions are filler, i.e. the order of application must stay the same.
This is an exercise to better understand the aforementioned operators.

Comment: Fully replace the brackets, or is it allowed to introduce new ones?

Comment: Fully replace, yes.

Comment: Use of the where clause works and scales up well to more complex examples. `mul s 5 where s = add 2 3`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the combinator `flip` to allow you to reverse the order of the arguments. each following line is equivalent:

```
mul (add 2 3) 5
(flip mul) 5 (add 2 3)
flip mul 5 $ add 2 3
```

`flip` is defined as simply:

```
flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> (b -> a -> c)
flip f b a = f a b
```

However, I don't believe the two operators `.` and `$` alone are sufficient

Comment: I think that is as close as we can get if the requirements of the OP are taken literally.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the algebraic properties of mul:

```
mul 5 $ add 2 3
```

Comment: If and only if the actual used function has that property, see "the mul and add functions are filler".

Comment: Certainly, that line was intended to be interpreted as a precondition.